# getting request object instead of paramaters for wcfextras soap header send

Tags: wcf, soap

I have the following contract method call in a soap wcf service contract:

[SoapHeader("UserId", typeof(Header), Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.In)]
[OperationContract]
string DeleteVideoRequest(Guid id);

I'm using the wcfextras library to read in a userid header value (or I want to anyways). The problem I'm running into is once I add the soapheader attribute the generated service signature wants a DeleteVideoRequestRequest (made up of the user id and guid id) object instead of a Guid. I'm not sure what is causing this to occur. Is this the expected behavior? I would expect that the signature stay the same, and then you would use the wcfextras code to read the header. Could I be missing something or doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. I was missing config values for the extras on the client side.